# How to understand $\frac{d}{dt}\{(\exp(tX))_*(Y)\}|_{t=0}=[X,Y]$?

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, representation-theory, intuition, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a [Lie group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) on which $X$ and $Y$ are two vector fields. Let $G\xrightarrow{\exp(tX)} G$ be the [(Lie theory) exponential map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map#Lie_theory) corresponding to $X$. Then of fundamental importance is \begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\{(\exp(tX))_*(Y)\}|_{t=0}=[X,Y]
\end{equation} 
where $[\cdot,\cdot]$ is the Lie bracket, and $\exp(tX)_*$ is the differential map induced from $\exp(tX)$.

Staring at this equation for a while, the only way I can prove it is by relating this exponential map to the [(Remannian) exponential map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map#Riemannian_geometry). This proof involves a lot differential geometry, which seems rather unnecessary, and does not seem very instructive.

I am wondering whether someone can share a more elegant proof (more direct, less differential geometry) or just some intuitive idea about how one should understand this equation.

Thanks very much!

Comment: I would suggest that you do this calculation on $G=GL(n)$. With the appropriate invariant metric, $\exp$ is just matrix exponential, and, of course, Lie bracket is just the matrix commutator. Just don't forget to make everything happen at the identity matrix. Decide whether your Lie algebra is left- or right-invariant vector fields and compute appropriately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a very general fact, and does not need fancy extra structure like that of a Lie group (or even a Riemannian structure):

If you have two smooth vector fields $X,Y$ on a smooth manifold $M$ (for simplicity, assume complete vector fields), and if $\phi_t: M \to M$ denotes the flow of $X$, then 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0} (\phi_t)_* Y = [X,Y].$$
(Important: Note that the $(\phi_t)_*$ on the left hand side denotes the push-forward of a diffeomorphism acting on vector fields, and not mereley the fiber-wise map!)

**Add.:** There are two maps, which are sometimes denoted with a $*$: Suppose you have a smooth map $\psi: M \to N$ between manifolds (we could have $M=N$, but the general version might be clearer).

1. Given a tangent vector $v\in T_pM$ at a point, there is the fiber-wise map $\psi_*:T_pM \to T_{\psi(p)}N$ that maps $ v\mapsto \psi_* v$. It takes a vector at $p$ and maps it to a vector at the image point $\psi(p)$. This works for any smooth map $\psi:M \to N$.
2. If $\psi$ is a *diffeomorphism*, then we can also do the following. Given a vector field $X\in \Gamma(TM)$, we can map it via $\psi$ to vector field $\psi_*X\in \Gamma(TN)$. This is the push-forward map. We obtain $\psi_*X$ as follows: Given $q\in N$, let $p = \psi^{-1}(q)\in M$ be its preimage. Note that $X_p\in T_pM$ is a tangent vector. We can map $X_p$ to a tangent vector $\psi_* (X_p) \in T_{\psi(p)}N$ with the map from (1). The value of $\psi_*X$ at $q = \psi(p)$ is obtained by setting $(\psi_*X)_q := \psi_* (X_p)$. Doing this for every $q\in N$ gives us a vector field $[q\mapsto (\psi_*X)_q]\in \Gamma(TN)$. 
   By this process, we obtain a map $\psi_*: \Gamma(TM)\to \Gamma(TN)$ which is explicitly given by $$\psi_*: \Gamma(TM)\to \Gamma(TN), \quad [p\mapsto X_p] \mapsto [q\mapsto \psi_*(X_{\psi^{-1}(q)})].$$ The push-forward acting on vector fields. It only makes sense for diffeomorphisms in general and is a way of transporting vector fields from one place to another.

Now let $f\in C^\infty(M)$ be an arbitrary smooth function. To prove the above identity, we need to show that $\left(\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} (\phi_t)_\ast Y \right) f = [X,Y]f$. Remember that the push-forward $(\phi_t)_\ast X$ is defined by $$((\phi_t)_* Y )_pf = (\phi_{t})_\ast (Y_{\phi_{-t}(p)})f = Y_{\phi_{-t}(p)}(f\circ \phi_{t})$$ for all $p\in M$. Thus
\begin{align}
 \left(\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} (\phi_t)_\ast Y \right) {}_p f &= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{((\phi_t)_* Y )_pf - Y_pf}{t} \\
&= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{Y_{\phi_{-t}(p)}(f\circ \phi_{t}) - Y_pf}{t} \\
&= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{Y_{\phi_{-t}(p)}(f\circ \phi_{t}) - Y_{\phi_{-t}}f}t +\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{Y_{\phi_{-t}(p)}f -Y_pf}{t} \\
&= \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{Y_{\phi_{-t}(p)}(f\circ \phi_{t}-f)}t +\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{(Yf)(\phi_{-t}(p)) -(Yf)(p)}{t} \\
&= Y_p\left(\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f\circ \phi_{t} - f}{t}\right) +\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{(Yf)(\phi_{-t}(p)) -(Yf)(p)}{t}  \\
&= Y_p(Xf) - X_p(Yf) \\
&= [X,Y]_p f.
\end{align}

(the sign convention for the Lie brackets is $[X,Y]= YX-XY$ or $[X,Y] = XY-YX$, depending on preference.)

In your case $\phi_t = \exp(tX)$ is the flow of $X$.

Comment: Note: There may be some issue with the sign conventions here... (so maybe your definitions are a bit different). But its o.k. in spirit.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "on the left hand side denotes the push-forward of a diffeomorphism acting on vector fields, and not mereley the fiber-wise map!"? I guess that is where things become confusing.

Comment: @HuiYu made some edits.

Comment: Sorry for the necropost: Is this the Lie derivative of the flow?

Comment: I am just used to the notation $\phi_{-t}$ in terms of flows, and flows are related to Lie derivatives.

Comment: @Gary: Yes, this is precisely the Lie derivative. It might well be that the conventions regarding signs differ.

Comment: Thanks, Sam, that clarifies it.